# Why Android ART sometimes won't GC local variables upon leaving their scopes?

Tags: android, variables, memory, garbage-collection, local

**It seems to me that, sometimes ART will GC local variables upon leaving their scopes, but sometimes it won't take place. It also seems to me that, it will always take place for Dalvik.**

I've used the Android Studio memory monitor to run the following test cases. They're all about the method testMemoryUsage added in onCreate:

```
@Override
protected final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    testMemoryUsage(); // For testing only
    setupActivity(); // Added to setup the activity to be ready to run
}
```

**Test Case 1(Control)**

testMemoryUsage is just an empty method:

```
// For testing only
private void testMemoryUsage() {
}
```

**Test Case 2(Non Final Local Variable)**

testMemoryUsage just creates a non final local variable uniqueStrings:

```
// For testing only
private void testMemoryUsage() {
    List<String> uniqueStrings = new Vector<>();
    for (Integer index = 0; index < 1000000; index++) {
        uniqueStrings.add(index.toString());
    }
}
```

**Testing Flow**

About every 10 seconds, the app will be closed by pressing the device back button and immediately reopened by clicking the app icon.

**Testing Devices**

GT-N7000(Android version 4.1.2) - Dalvik

LG-D802(Android version 4.4.2) - Dalvik

LG-H860(Android version 6.0.1) - ART

Nexus 5X(Android version 7.0) - ART

By using 2 devices, each with different Android version, with Dalvik and 2 devices, each with different Android version, with ART, this setup should eliminate the variables due to devices and Android versions rather than Dalvik and ART.

**Memory Monitor Results**

[Memory Monitor Result 1(LG-H860 in **Test Case 1**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgbrL.png)

Nexus 5X(ART) shows the essentially similar memory monitor results as it's the control test case. **However, both GT-N7000(Dalvik) and LG-D802(Dalvik) show nearly flat results.**

[Memory Monitor Result 2(LG-H860 in **Test Case 2**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inepO.png)

Nexus 5X(ART) shows the essentially similar memory monitor results. **However, both GT-N7000(Dalvik) and LG-D802(Dalvik) show sawtooth-like results with the dropping edge being triggered upon finishing adding all those 1000000 unique strings, meaning that Dalvik always immediately GC the local variable uniqueStrings upon leaving its scope testMemoryUsage.**

In the case of ART, it sometimes does GC the local variable uniqueStrings upon leaving its scope testMemoryUsage for the 1st and 2nd app launches, but sometimes it doesn't. Also, sometimes such GC takes place for subsequent closing and reopenings, but sometimes it does.

I've run these tests for nearly 10 times each on LG-H860(ART) and Nexus 5X(ART), and the memory monitor results are quite inconsistent(the aforementioned "sometimes") even for the same test on the same testing device, except 1 point - Either the GC will immediately take place upon the aforementioned timings, or it won't take place no matter how long I wait, although it might take place if I do something else inside the app. **However, the memory monitor results for GT-N7000(Dalvik) and LG-D802(Dalvik) are very consistent.**

I've tried to search on the internet for answers, but I failed to find anything despite hours of effort, so I decided to ask here:

**Is ART really the source of all these issues, or did I make some terrible mistakes?**

Answer (score 1):

ART's GC algorithm is different from Dalvik's GC algorithm. Dalvik would get triggered as soon as an app exited and many times even as the app would be running causing UI thread pauses due to blocked operations. In your expirement, the Dalvik behaviour is perfect, it triggers as soon as the app is exited and does a concurrent GC sweep to clear out memory.

ART's default plan is the CMS (concurrent mark sweep) plan, which uses mostly sticky CMS and partial CMS. Sticky CMS is ART’s non-moving generational garbage collector. It scans only the portion of the heap that was modified since the last GC and can reclaim only the objects allocated since the last GC. In addition to the CMS plan, ART performs heap compaction when an app changes process state to a jank-imperceptible process state (e.g. background or cached). So you see that the ART's GC behaviour is perfect and it waits for its next GC sweep cycle to clear out memory. This helps in two ways:

1. There aren't asynchronous GC sweeps. So the number of GC sweeps are reduced as compared to Dalvik.
2. In your case, since the app is immediately relaunched, memory is reused appropriately.

So ART is not the source of all these issues, but it is how it will behave  as per it's design.

You will get more detailed info [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/gc-debug.html)

Comment: I've read that article before asking this, but your answer helps me make more sense of it. Thanks.